# How can I display an image and add it as an attachment to an email

Tags: c#, email

I am creating a System.Net.Mail message with an html body. I attach a jpeg image (from a byte aray) of the customer's signature to the email and send to a service center. The service center wanted to see the signature without having to open the attachment so I changed the html and added the image again as a LinkedResource. The problem is, now the attachment is larger than before and attempting to view the attachment displays an error. If I save the attachment and open the file in a hex editor the entire file is empty. I can comment the code that adds the linked resource and the attachment works again. How can I include the inline image, and the attachment?

This is the tag I embed to image in: `<p><img src=cid:CustomerSignature /></p>`

This is my code:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(insuranceClaim.Signature, 0, insuranceClaim.Signature.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
contentType.Name = "signature.jpg";
System.Net.Mail.Attachment imageAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, contentType);
System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition disposition = imageAttachment.ContentDisposition;
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(imageAttachment);
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource signature = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(ms, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("image/jpeg"));
signature.ContentId = "CustomerSignature";
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView aView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
aView.LinkedResources.Add(signature);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(aView);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like answering my own questions, but if someone else makes the same mistake I did, here is the solution. I created a new MemoryStream with the image data, and tried to share the stream between the attachment, and the LinkedResource. Once I created 2 MemoryStreams it worked.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(insuranceClaim.Signature, 0, insuranceClaim.Signature.Length);
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
contentType.Name = "signature.jpg";
System.Net.Mail.Attachment imageAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, contentType);
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(imageAttachment);

System.IO.MemoryStream embeddedMs = new System.IO.MemoryStream(insuranceClaim.Signature, 0, insuranceClaim.Signature.Length);
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource signature = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(embeddedMs, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("image/jpeg"));
signature.ContentId = "CustomerSignature";
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView aView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
aView.LinkedResources.Add(signature);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(aView);
```

Comment: My problem was different: I was not converting my image to Byte array. Your post helped me anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using image/jpeg as content type for an image does not work. It attempts to embed the image in the email and converts it to base64.  Then the sender, recipient and subject are blanked out. Sends the email but all information is corrupt.